# Firebase Persistence not working on React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, persistence

When I close or reload my app, I am always logged out, no matter the persistence.  Any ideas?

My persistence implementation:

```js
import { getReactNativePersistence } from "firebase/auth/react-native";
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import {
  initializeAuth,
  getAuth,
  onAuthStateChanged,
} from "firebase/auth";

const persistence = getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage);
const FIREBASE_APP = !getApps().length
  ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
  : getApp();
export const FIREBASE_AUTH = !getApps().length
  ? initializeAuth(FIREBASE_APP, { persistence })
  : getAuth(FIREBASE_APP);
```

Checking for auth state change:

```js
export const authObserver = () => {
  onAuthStateChanged(FIREBASE_AUTH, async (authUser) => {
    try {
      if (authUser) {
        console.log("User logged in");
        processUser(authUser);
      } else {
        console.log("Not logged in"); // Always goes here after reload.
      }
    } catch (err) {
      clearStorage("authUser");
      clearStorage("user");
      console.log("ERR:", err);
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my problem.  `getApps.length` returns 1 before setting the auth so it never chose the persistent ternary route.

My new code:

```js
const persistence = getReactNativePersistence(AsyncStorage);
const initializing = !getApps().length;
const FIREBASE_APP = initializing ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
export const FIREBASE_AUTH = initializing
  ? initializeAuth(FIREBASE_APP, { persistence })
  : getAuth(FIREBASE_APP);
```